# beamer: missing footline in version 3.28, bug or feature?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I updated my texlive distribution today. After compiling my presentation I realised, that the `Boadilla` theme has no footline any more. A look in the documentation shows, that nearly every theme in chapter 15.2 lost its footline. However, a closer look shows, that the place for the footline with respect to the navigation symbols is kept free. These symbols are directly at the bottom of a template with no footline. Compare for instance `EastLansing` with `Pittsburgh`.

`EastLansing` from version 3.27:
[image]

`EastLansing` from version 3.28:
[image]

The space between the navigation symbols and the bottom is much higher than in `Pittsburgh` from version 3.28:
[image]

Is this a bug, or do I miss an option to enable the footline?

Comment: Bug: reported and logged in the issues database (https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/258/footline-not-showing-with-infolines-outer) and fixed in an upcoming CTAN update.

Comment: Thanks! Google did not show me this result and I missed to take a look at the repo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug report.
